# Unable to load the image

Tags: c#, html, typescript

Unable to add image.
I am unable to upload the image in browser using the code as show below

When i try to run the code, image is not displaying, in console it showing the error has below:
**a1.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**
\\\

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Myproject</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="assests/a1.jpg" height="20" width="40">

  </div>

  <div>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no code...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: 404 means the file isn't found. Is your app looking in the correct server folder? Are you using a relative path or an absolute one?

Answer (score 1):

There is a spelling error in assets. Spell it **assets** and not **assests** and try again